# Windows batch file to download latest file in s3 bucket folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a windows batch script that will get me the name of the latest file in a folder in an s3 bucket.  I want to use the output to download that file to the local machine.

Here is the current output from the AWS S3 ls command:

```
2017-12-19 13:28:51          0  
2018-01-09 16:13:03 380093544960 FULL-BK-OLD.bak  
2019-09-10 23:44:37 101958829056 Backup_FULL_20190910_164900.bak  
2019-09-23 23:45:15 76693135360 Backup_FULL_20190923_120027.bak  
2019-09-30 23:45:10 76976559104 Backup_FULL_20190930_120025.bak  
2019-10-05 23:45:11 79225411584 Backup_FULL_20191005_120025.bak
```

The goal:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/backups/%latestFile% .
```

Comment: My advice, as cmd.exe's built-in and cli utilities don't understand how to translate date strings to actual date objects is to seek the help of another language. PowerShell is my recommendation.

Comment: Any idea how to convert the output to a table in Powershell?  Piping to format-table doesn't seem to do anything.  I can get it sorted but that is about all I can do to the output.  Any direction would be appreciated.